# scala: Loop through a file to read 20 bytes at a time and blank out bytes at 3rd position

Tags: scala

I have a code snippet in java that loops through the file byte by byte and blanks out byte at 3rd position on every 20 bytes. This is done using for each loop.

```
logic:
for(byte b: raw){
 if (pos is 3) b = 32;
 if (i > 20) i = 0; 
 i++
}
```

Since I am learning scala, I would like to know if there is a better way of looping byte by byte in scala.

I have read into byte array as below in scala:

```
val result = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream (new File(fileDir)))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Defining variable `pos` somewhere would certainly be a better way, regardless of the language used. And maybe actually doing something inside of the `for`-loop would make more sense rather than just iterating.

Comment: Better in what aspect? Faster, more readable, more functional? Quite often these targets are on the opposite ends. What is `pos` by the way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a diametrically opposite solution to that of Tzach Zohar:

```
def parallel(ba: Array[Byte], blockSize: Int = 2048): Unit = {
  val n = ba.size
  val numJobs = (n + blockSize - 1) / blockSize
  (0 until numJobs).par.foreach { i =>
    val startIdx = i * blockSize
    val endIdx = n min ((i + 1) * blockSize)
    var j = startIdx + ((3 - startIdx) % 20 + 20) % 20
    while (j < endIdx) {
      ba(j) = 32
      j += 20
    }
  }
}
```

You see a lot of mutable variables, scary imperative while-loops, and some strange tricks with modular arithmetic. That's actually not idiomatic Scala at all. But the interesting thing about this solution is that it processes blocks of the byte array in parallel. I've compared the time needed by this solution to your naive solution, using various block sizes:

```
Naive:          38.196
Parallel(  16): 11.676000
Parallel(  32): 7.260000
Parallel(  64): 4.311000
Parallel( 128): 2.757000
Parallel( 256): 2.473000
Parallel( 512): 2.462000
Parallel(1024): 2.435000
Parallel(2048): 2.444000
Parallel(4096): 2.416000
Parallel(8192): 2.420000
```

At least in this not very thorough microbenchmark (1000 repetitions on 10MB array), the more-or-less efficiently implemented parallel version outperformed the for-loop in your question by factor 15x.

The question is now: What do you mean by "better"?

- My proposal was slightly faster than your naive approach
- @TzachZohar's functional solution could generalize better should the
  code be moved on a cluster like Apache Spark.
- I would usually prefer something closer to @TzachZohar's solution, because it's easier to read.

So, it depends on what you are optimizing for: performance? generality? readability? maintainability? For each notion of "better", you could get a different answer. I've tried to optimize for performance. @TzachZohar optimized for readability and maintainability. That lead to two rather different solutions.

---

Full code of the microbenchmark, just in case someone is interested:

```
val array = Array.ofDim[Byte](10000000)

def naive(ba: Array[Byte]): Unit = {
  var pos = 0
  for (i <- 0 until ba.size) {
    if (pos == 3) ba(i) = 32
    pos += 1
    if (pos == 20) pos = 0
  }
}

def parallel(ba: Array[Byte], blockSize: Int): Unit = {
  val n = ba.size
  val numJobs = (n + blockSize - 1) / blockSize
  (0 until numJobs).par.foreach { i =>
    val startIdx = i * blockSize
    val endIdx = n min ((i + 1) * blockSize)
    var j = startIdx + ((3 - startIdx) % 20 + 20) % 20
    while (j < endIdx) {
      ba(j) = 32
      j += 20
    }
  }
}

def measureTime[U](repeats: Long)(block: => U): Double = {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis

  var iteration = 0
  while (iteration < repeats) {
    iteration += 1
    block
  }

  val end = System.currentTimeMillis
  (end - start).toDouble / repeats
}

println("Basic sanity check (did I get the modulo arithmetic right?):")

{
  val testArray = Array.ofDim[Byte](50)
  naive(testArray)
  println(testArray.mkString("[", ",", "]"))
}
{
  for (blockSize <- List(3, 7, 13, 16, 17, 32)) {
    val testArray = Array.ofDim[Byte](50)
    parallel(testArray, blockSize)
    println(testArray.mkString("[", ",", "]"))
  }
}

val Reps = 1000

val naiveTime = measureTime(Reps)(naive(array))

println("Naive:          " + naiveTime)
for (blockSize <- List(16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192)) {
  val parallelTime = measureTime(Reps)(parallel(array, blockSize))
  println("Parallel(%4d): %f".format(blockSize, parallelTime))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do this:

```
val updated = result.grouped(20).flatMap { arr => arr.update(3, 32); arr }
```

Comment: A `map` followed by `flatten`. If only there were some way to combine them. ;o)

Comment: Thank you. Let me try. I was looking at map functions but didn't know how to split 20 bytes.

Comment: @jwvh oops caught me in my hasty answering... thanks, will update.